# Replace Starter 2002 Jetta

Tags: vw, jetta, starter

I'm trying to replace the starter in my 2002 jetta 1.8T, however it's a different starter - I think it's called an Hitachi Starter. There is a cable running across the top of it in a notched area. I'm just looking for a little guidance on how to replace it. I'm not sure if I can disconnect that cable or what exactly is needed.

Comment: Is this the AWW engine? Which transmission do you have? Can you take pictures of what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, we can't help much with so little information.